# Shortcut for "Next" window in Windows 8 (or 7 or XP)

Tags: windows, windows-8, keyboard-shortcuts, autohotkey, alt-tab

I want to have a shortcut for the next window in the open windows

I do know about <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> but that's not what I want.

- <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> will cycle between 2 windows.
- <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> will cycle between 3 windows and so on.

(I have explored on how <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> functions and I don't think it's of any use here.)

I simply want to get the next window in the window pile.

I am open to all free third-party options. Moreover, I also use Autohotkey. So, if there's any script for this feature, that would also work with me.

Answer (score 8):

I think <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Esc</kbd> will fill your need. Pressing it once to switch to the **next open window**. It doesn't switch between *recently used windows*

> Unfortunately, with all this excitement attached to <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>, another hotkey has been woefully neglected. Windows 2.0 introduced the <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Esc</kbd> hotkey. Whereas <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> lets you pick an application, <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Esc</kbd> lets you cycle through them.
>
> When you press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Esc</kbd>, the active window is sent to the bottom of the window stack, allowing the window beneath it in the z-order to become the new active window. And if the next window is a minimized window, it stays minimized. While this may sound like an annoyance, it is actually a useful device, as it lets you skip past minimized applications without having to open them.
>
> [Raymond Chen Discusses the `Alt+Tab` and `Alt+Esc` Hotkeys](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/technet-magazine/dd424927(v=msdn.10))

Comment: Awesome! And here I was thinking I know all the keyboard shortcuts in Windows...
Thanks..

Comment: A small query here. Since I am on windows 8, Alt+Tab switches between both desktop and metro apps. But Alt+Esc switches only between desktop apps. Any solution?

Comment: win+tab switch between metro apps, but currently I'm not on windows 8 to check. Anyway in this case I think an Autohotkey solution is better

Answer (score 1):

You can use  **7+ Taskbar Tweaker**.

Go to Advanced Options > Keyboard Shortcuts.

You can press `Help` button to learn how to use.
For example, to set <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd> and <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd> to cycle through windows, insert these rules:

| Name | Data |
| --- | --- |
| 0x51|alt | 102 |
| 0x51|alt+shift | 101 |

*I preferred to use <kbd>Alt</kbd>(+<kbd>Shift</kbd>)+<kbd>Q</kbd> and keep <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>'s behavior, because it's still more likely to switch to previous active window, than cycle in an ordered form (you can experience it). Also <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> is already used for desktop management and giving a good view of windows, <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd> is used for search and <kbd>Alt</kbd>(+<kbd>Shift</kbd>)+<kbd>Grave Accent</kbd> is less handy. Furthermore, <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd> is less used in different programs, than <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd>, <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> or <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd>, ....*