# Shortcut to switch to 'next' window in Windows 10

Tags: windows, windows-10, keyboard-shortcuts

I would like to know how to simply switch to the 'next' application on Windows 10 via keyboard shortcut without having to interact with the pop-up window. Instead of having to hold down alt and tab through the GUI, I just want a repeatable keystroke that just directly switches to the next app. Alt-Tab bounces you back and forth between the same two apps. Is this doable without changing to a different Window manager like bug.n?

Comment: There is no "next" just a list of apps. Hold down Alt and then Tab cycles to all the apps (not just cycles between two unless there are just two active apps)

Comment: But clearly the list has an ordering, or else the cycling would have no arrangement. As I said in my question, I understand that I can tab through the available apps by holding down Alt. However, this happens with a GUI. I am looking for a way to cycle through the applications via the keyboard without the GUI.

Comment: Alt - Tab is a keystroke. So that works very well for me. There is no standard ordering. Just the list of what is there

Comment: @user242007, I think you need to clarify better what exactly you mean by "next app".  It's unclear to me what you want that alt-tab doesn't already provide. The ordering of the window list shown by alt-tab is (roughly) by most recently used so it's dynamic.  That's why alt-tab can cycle between two applications easily.  Maybe Alt+Esc is what you want?

Comment: **Alt + Escape** is the non _cool switch_ way. It is organised by recently used windows eg the Z order.

Comment: What is your use case exactly ? Do you know the number of apps that will be running ? Are you trying to use that on your day-to-day machine ?

Answer (score 10):

```
Key Description 
Alt + Esc Switches to the next open window 

Alt + Shift + Esc Switches to the previous open window 

Alt + Tab Cycles through open windows, and switches to the window when the Alt key is released. This is known as Coolswitch. Pressing Escape cancels switching windows. 


Alt + Shift + Tab Cycles backwards through open windows, and switches to the window when the Alt key is released. This is known as Coolswitch. Pressing Escape cancels switching windows.

Ctrl + Alt + Tab Vista: Starts Windows Coolswitch. Use Arrow keys, Tab, or Shift + Tab to navigate and Enter or Space to activate. Pressing Escape cancels switching windows. 

Winkey + T Toggle speech dictation mode.
Vista: Cycles through Taskbar buttons, Press Enter or Space to activate a window. This is same as Winkey + Tab in older versions. 

Winkey + Tab Cycles through Taskbar buttons, Press Enter or Space to activate a window.
Vista: Cycles through open windows using Windows Flip3D. Release keys to activate window. Pressing Escape cancels switching windows. 

Winkey + Ctrl + Tab Cycles through parts of the desktop and taskbar.
Vista: Starts Windows Flip3D. Use Arrow keys, Tab, or Shift + Tab to navigate and Enter or Space to activate. Pressing Escape cancels switching windows.
```

Windows Vista changed the Alt+Tab order slightly

> For decades, the Alt+Tab order was the same as the Z-order, but that
>   changes in Windows Vista if you use the enhanced Alt+Tab feature known
>   as Flip, which is on by default on most systems. There are three types
>   of interactive task switching in Windows Vista:
>
> Classic Alt+Tab: This is the same one that's been around since Windows
>   95. It shows a grid of icons.
>
> Flip (new for Windows Vista): This shows a grid of thumbnails.
>
> Flip3D (also new for Windows Vista): This shows a stack of windows in
>   3D.
>
> Classic Alt+Tab continues to show the icons in Z-order order, but the
>   developer who wrote Flip told me that Flip changed it up a bit based
>   on feedback from the design team. The first several icons are still
>   shown in Z-order order, but if you have a lot of windows open, the
>   rest of them are shown in alphabetical order to make it easier to pick
>   the one you want from the list. I think it's a good sign that nobody
>   seems to have noticed. A lot of user interface work tries to be
>   invisible.

Posted by oldnewthing

> The icons appear in the same order as the window Z-order. When you
>   switch to a window, then it comes to the top of the Z-order. If you
>   minimize a window, it goes to the bottom of the Z-order. The Alt+Esc
>   hotkey (gosh, does anybody still use Alt+Esc?) takes the current top
>   window and sends it to the bottom of the Z-order (and the window next
>   in line comes to the top). The Alt+Shift+Esc hotkey (I bet you didn't
>   know that hotkey even existed) takes the bottom-most window and brings
>   it to the top, but does not open the window if it is minimized.
>
> The presence of "always on top" windows makes this a little more
>   complicated. The basic rule is that an "always on top" window always
>   appears on top of a "not always on top" window. So if the above rules
>   indicate that a "not always on top" window comes to the top, it really
>   just goes as high as it can without getting on top of any "always on
>   top" windows.
>
> You may have run across the term "fast task switching". This was the
>   term used to describe the precursor to the current Alt+Tab switching
>   interface. The old way of switching via Alt+Tab (Windows 3.0 and
>   earlier) was just like Alt+Esc, except that the window you switched to
>   was automatically opened if it had been minimized. When the new
>   Alt+Tab was added to Windows 3.1, we were concerned that people might
>   prefer the old way, so there was a switch in the control panel to set
>   it back to the slow way. (There is also a setting
>   SPI_SETFASTTASKSWITCH that lets you change it programmatically.) It
>   turns out nobody complained, so the old slow way of task switching was
>   removed entirely and the setting now has no effect.
>
> This does highlight the effort we take to try to allow people who
>   don't like the new way of doing something to go back to the old way.
>   It turns out that corporations with 10,000 employees don't like it
>   when the user interface changes, because it forces them to spend
>   millions of dollars retraining all their employees. If you open up the
>   Group Policy Editor, you can see the zillions of deployment settings
>   that IT administrators can use to disable a variety of new Windows UI
>   features.

Published Monday, October 20, 2003 3:58 AM by *oldnewthing*

Answer (score 1):

You can use  **7+ Taskbar Tweaker**. Read [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/1680471/764600).

Answer (score 0):

Another good option is using this AutoHotkey script https://github.com/JuanmaMenendez/AutoHotkey-script-Open-Show-Apps which allows switching between opened windows of the same app (like macOS) and additionally you can Open and Minimize any App you set.