# Disable MRU in Alt+Tab task switch

Tags: windows-7, windows-xp, alt-tab

Is it possible to disable most-recently-used ordering of windows' task switching (alt-tab) and use cycling instead? ie., always the same order (no matter how you use, independent of z-order).

I found a workaround with autohotkey called [taskbarnavigation](http://www.autohotkey.com/board/topic/91577-taskbarnavigation-switch-windows-in-taskbar-order-alt-tab-replacement/) by *robertcollier4*, based on [activatebynum](https://code.google.com/p/activatebynum/).

It's great! Some issues though: it doesn't feature that built-in "icon cycle window" (?) that windows shows when you press `Alt`+`Tab` in bare Windows. Also the `.ahk` script is said *not* to work in Windows 7. <del>Also, it's performance is not perfect.</del> Furthermore I may not want to activate every single window along the way.

**UPDATE**: with TaskbarNavigation 1.3, the performance issues can be resolved, thanks to RobertCollier4!

Is there a(n other) way to change task-switching order from MRU to cycle-in-order?

Comment: An alternative such as [this](http://www.ntwind.com/software/vistaswitcher.html) might help.

Comment: @Karan I'm testing this but cannot actually find an option that disables MRU. Gone through all the preferences window. Are you sure there is one? Could you perhaps help me find it?

Comment: Haven't used it extensively myself. I only briefly tried it long time back, and it occurred to me perhaps it might help you in *some* way, even if it cannot do what you specifically asked for.

Comment: @Karan it has nice features, however, there is an, albeit personal, reason I specifically looking for this, which is I have to admit after all these years that MRU irritates me actually. But thanks! :)

Comment: I'll look around for solutions. BTW, does this at least allow Alt+Tab to Desktop in XP?

Comment: @Karan no, I can't seem to find an option for that either.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/9284/discussion-between-naxa-and-karan)

Answer (score 2):

For Win7, the tool [7+ Taskbar Tweaker](http://rammichael.com/7-taskbar-tweaker) can assign a keyboard shortcut to cycle back and forward in visual taskbar order. See the help file under section Advanced>Keyboard Shortcuts. It lets you assign key codes to actions 101 and 102:

```
101 - Switch to the window which is located on the left to the active window on the taskbar. 
102 - Switch to the window which is located on the right to the active window on the taskbar.
```

For Windows XP, which is still a preferred OS to me due to superior responsiveness of UI - TaskbarNavigation seems to be the only currently available solution. There were previously some quirks with Windows not allowing applications to steal focus causing the window to not come to focus but only flash on taskbar. See [SetForegroundWindow restrictions](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/76427/How-to-bring-window-to-top-with-SetForegroundWindo) problem for which TaskbarNavigation implements some hackish Dllcalls.

However with recent investigation, there may be better methods with [SystemParametersInfo(win32con.SPI_SETFOREGROUNDLOCKTIMEOUT](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6312627/1781201) or [emulating the Alt key before switching](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13881647/1781201) or [DllCall to RegisterHotKey](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2009/02/26/9445006.aspx).

If you want to provide some more feedback on the AutoHotkey forum regarding where performance is to be desired, perhaps it can be improved/fixed/perfected. Adding ["#UseHook, Off"](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/_UseHook.htm) may also fix problems.

Cross-linking to related:

- [Hotkey to switch between windows in taskbar order in Windows 7 [superuser.com]](https://superuser.com/questions/468267/hotkey-to-switch-between-windows-in-taskbar-order-in-windows-7)
- [superuser.com: Switching between taskbar tasks sequentially [superuser.com]](https://superuser.com/questions/256318/switching-between-taskbar-tasks-sequentially)

Comment: fantastic program! I can't seem to be able to override alt+[tab](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd375731%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) though. I'm trying it with `0x09|alt`, set value (dword, *Decimal*, 101). it works with other shortcut keys but not with those built-in.

Comment: also 101 and 102 unfortunately also *activates* the window. I have this same problem with `TaskbarNavigation`, I don't really want to *activate* the window, just select it. (In this case similar to `win+T` in 7, but start from the currently active process, not always from the first.)

Comment: You will have to ask the author of 7+ Taskbar Tweaker (not me). However one solution I can think of is to assign an intermediary hotkey such as Ctrl+F11 and Ctrl+F12 in 7+ Taskbar Tweaker - then use AutoHotkey to map Alt+Tab and Alt+Shift+Tab to those intermediary hotkeys (AutoHotkey can implement a more advanced keyboard hook that can remap Alt+Tab)

Comment: sure! added it more for the record. funny thing that we have these OS for what 20+ years, selling another version every now and then, and all but this simple thing cannot be achieved, no? :) I mean do anyone actually care for these OSes. At least Linux distros you always has the source code as last resort. ;P

Comment: <<I don't really want to activate the window, just select it.>> Yes, I tried to do this in TaskbarNavigation however was unable to figure it out with the [Win Taskbar API Calls](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb762722%28VS.85%29.aspx) (tried all of them such as TB_SETHOTITEM). If anyone has any info, this is a wish of mine as well.

Comment: If you still want to do this in Windows XP, you can try TaskbarNavigation v1.3 (new bugfix version just updated and released) which is now mapped to Alt+Tab or Numpad keys instead of Win+arrows. Turns out that Alt modified keys or Numpad keys are considered "special" hotkeys by Windows for which it automatically disables its SetForegroundWindow restrictions. (More info at MSDN LockSetForegroundWindow). Thus if you use one of these special hotkeys it does not require any of the previous DllCall hacks. Therefore switching now works 100% of the time and speed feels like native alt+tab.

Comment: wonderful! thank you so much! you continue to impress me with your work, RobertCollier! Just tried, it works seamlessly and perfectly. It really is very convenient (of course my girlfriend will be confused if she tries to use my numpad:).) The extra benefit is that now alt+tab still functions, so you have actually two means of task-switching supporting each other. I've an ms ergonomic 4000, i may once try to map this into non-standard keys, or depending on the numlock state.

Comment: OK, so I realized that the win+num usage conflicted with the closed-source reSizer I use, and unfortunately for this matter, also like. :) (That's the cause I never actually got numbers working before, but now it works because I turned reSizer off. Also I was trying the "other" number keys before, which surprisingly didn't worked... maybe also due to reSizer. I shall look into how to resolve this conflict... Also, so nice icon and menu, which I didn't mentioned yet! :)

Comment: I have released TaskbarNavigation 1.4 with a "ListHotkeys Debug" menu entry and a method to make sure that a hotkey will work 100% of the time. If you want to configure your own custom hotkeys, read post #10: http://www.autohotkey.com/board/topic/91577-taskbarnavigation-switch-windows-in-taskbar-order-alt-tab-replacement/#entry604360

Comment: I still test it, but very appreciate that you gave this announcement and more so the work of course! This is one piece of must have litte software! :D